# SendMessageTimeout with BM_CLICK never return

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-messages

I'm trying to send BM_CLICK to a window in another process.

When the target button get clicked, the target window pops up a modal dialog, then my calling thread never return even I send the timeout to 1 second.

```
SendMessageTimeout(handle, BM_CLICK, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG | SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, NULL);
```

What's the reason of this? Is there any idea I can prevent this?

There are some potential solutions:

1. Use PostMessage with WM_LBUTTONDOWN and WM_LBUTTONUP to simulate the click
2. If I remember correctly, PostMessage doesn't support BM_CLICK, isn't it?

Comment: Any one down vote this can give a reason?

Comment: `SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG` means to abort if the other side is hung, ie is not processing messages in a timely manner. Displaying a modal dialog is not a hang, since the modal loop processes messages. You can't combine `SMTO_NORMAL` with other flags since `SMTO_NORMAL` is 0.

Comment: In any case, don't simulate `WM_LBUTTON...` manually. That is exactly what `BM_CLICK` already does for you: "*This message causes the button to receive the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` messages, and the button's parent window to receive a `BN_CLICKED` notification code*". And yes, you can use `BM_CLICK` with `PostMessage()` (I tested it, it works fine), as `BM_CLICK` does not have a return value, so no need to wait for one.

Comment: As Remy wrote, `BM_CLICK` doesn't have a return value so there is no point at all in using `SendMessageTimeout()`. Just use `PostMessage()` and be done with it.

Comment: Modal dialog is not hung, that the tricky thing, is there anyway to make SendMessageTime returns after some time ignoring the modal dialog? I will try PostMessage anyway.

Comment: @RemyLebeau and zett42 You guys are awesome! PostMessage works. (My memory is not reliable)

Comment: Why not UI Automation?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Last time I gave up UI Automation is may because of lack of operations on non-expanded sub items in tree view. Seems that UI Automation doesn't handle invisible components very well. Correct me if I'm wrong.